# Add the corresponding maximum value in a new column for each month

Tags: r, dataframe, match

I've the following dataframe:

```r
df <- structure(list(locality_id = structure(c(3L, 1L, 2L, 4L), .Label = c("L2762894", 
"L3064193", "L6199859", "L8044094"), class = "factor"), month = structure(c(1L, 
3L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("1", "2", "3"), class = "factor"), prec01 = c(105, 
109, 133, 79), prec02 = c(29, 34, 34, 35), prec03 = c(18, 48, 
42, 184)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```

Each `locality` has `precipitation` values for the first `three months` `(prec01,  prec02, prec03)`.

I would like to create an unique precipitation column matching the corresponding precipitation value of each month to the corresponding month (column month). Resulting in something as follows:

```r
#   locality_id month prec
# 1    L6199859     1  105
# 2    L2762894     3  109
# 3    L3064193     1  133
# 4    L8044094     2  184
```

Any idea of how to do produce the above output?

Thank you!

Comment: If using a loop is possible for you (if speed is not an issue), then this looks trivial.

Comment: For a better solution that a loop, please have a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33542325/how-to-subset-a-matrix-with-different-column-positions-for-each-row (and the linked duplicated).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to subset a matrix with different column positions for each row?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33542325/how-to-subset-a-matrix-with-different-column-positions-for-each-row)

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your question you want to keep in the new `prec` column the corresponding value of `precXX` for that `month`?

In that case it seems to me that the example is not correct, but should instead be:

*Starting dataframe:*

```
  locality_id month prec01 prec02 prec03
1    L6199859     1    105     29     18
2    L2762894     3    109     34     48
3    L3064193     1    133     34     42
4    L8044094     2     79     35    184
```

*Final dataframe:*

```
 locality_id month prec
1    L6199859     1  105
2    L2762894     3   48
3    L3064193     1  133
4    L8044094     2   35
```

You may achieve that with matrix indexing:

```
i <- as.numeric(df$month)

df$prec <- df[,c(3,4,5)][cbind(seq_along(i), i)]

df[,c(-3,-4,-5)]
```